# jquery loop each object in json and swap text in html

Tags: jquery, json

I'm weak in jQuery and I need help. I want to display some text in html and after a few seconds, replace it with another. I have a JSON object that contains the array elements to display.

The problem:
The script displays only the last element in the JSON object. `setInterval` and `setTimeout` functions are working properly. If the text is appended, and not set, then the texts of all the elements are added and displayed in a single sentence. 
S
o `$.each` is working properly.

I've tried many variations and can not seem to manage to achieve the desired.

Generally two examples of code:

Example 1:

```
<script>
var list = "@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))";
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            $('#spinNaslov').text(list[i].Naslov);
            $('#spinBloger').text(list[i].Korisnik + ', ' + list[i].Datum);
        }            
    });
</script>
<div id="novostiSpin">
    <h2 id="spinNaslov" style="text-align:center; color:#fed8e6;"></h2>
    <span id="spinBloger" style="float:right; color:#999898; padding:5px;"></span> 
</div><br />
```

Last example:

```
<script>
var list = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
var i = 0;
$(document).ready(function () {
    swap(i);
})

function swap(index) {
    window.setInterval(function () {
        $('#spinNaslov').text('');
        $('#spinBloger').text('');

        $.each(list, function (index, item) {
            $.each(item, function (name, value) {
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    if (name == 'Naslov') {
                        $('#spinNaslov').text(value);
                    }
                    if (name == 'Korisnik') {
                        $('#spinBloger').text(value);
                    }
                }, 3000);
            });
            i++
        });
    }, 2000);
}        
</script>
<div id="novostiSpin">
    <h2 id="spinNaslov" style="text-align:center; color:#fed8e6;"></h2>
    <span id="spinBloger" style="float:right; color:#999898; padding:5px;"></span> 
</div><br />
```

The same behavior in both cases, please advice

That's it! **Thank you Deedbster** Before I saw your post I've almost come to a solution with a completely different code.

If you have time it would help me if you could tell me what I'm wrong. Following code does the same as yours, except that does not display the first or last element of the list.

```
<script>
var listCount = @Model.Count;
var list = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
var i = 0;
function naNulu() {
    i++;
    if(i===listCount-1) {
        i = 0;
    }
}
$(document).ready(function () {
window.setInterval(function () { swap(i) }, 2000);
})

function swap(index) {
$('#spinNaslov').text('');
$('#spinBloger').text('');

$.each(list, function (index, item) {
    $.each(item, function (name, value) {
        if (name == 'Naslov') {
            $('#spinNaslov').text(list[i].Naslov);
        }
        if (name == 'Korisnik') {
            $('#spinBloger').text(list[i].Korisnik);
        }
    }); naNulu();
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating over your *n* items and setting up *n* functions which are all running at once. Bear in mind that [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) does not block. Try reading [How JavaScript Timers Work](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) if you don't understand what I mean.

`setInterval` alone is sufficient here: just change the targets to the `list[i]` values inside your setInterval function. This is a combination of your two examples.

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Jp4fX/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var list = [
        {foo: 'Foo1', bar: 'Bar1', quux: 'Quux1'},
        {foo: 'Foo2', bar: 'Bar2', quux: 'Quux2'},
        {foo: 'Foo3', bar: 'Bar3', quux: 'Quux3'},
        {foo: 'Foo4', bar: 'Bar4', quux: 'Quux4'}
    ];
    var i = 0;

    i = swap(list, i);
    window.setInterval(function () {
        i = swap(list, i);
    }, 2000);
})

function swap(list, i) {
    $('#spinNaslov').text(list[i].foo);
    $('#spinBloger').text(list[i].bar + ', ' + list[i].quux);
    return (i + 1) % list.length;
}
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you Deedbster
Before I saw your post I've almost come to a solution with a completely different code.

If you have time it would help me if you could tell me what I'm wrong.
Following code does the same as yours, except that does not display the first or last element of the list.

Comment: I'm sorry I had to put the code in the edit of the original post.
If you could take a look and tell me what's the catch :-)

Comment: As before, your use of ```each``` is incorrect as you are repeatedly calling text(), although this time with the same value. Your check for ```i``` being too high is also incorrect, as you want to allow the ```listCount-1```th item as this is the last value.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I need to work on jQuery ... Can you please clarify this part --> (i + 1) % list.length;

Comment: I'm still low with a reputation for voting ... sorry

Comment: % is a modulus operation. It returns the remainder of division. E.g. 1 % 3 = 1, 2 % 3 = 2, 3 % 3 = 0, 4 % 3 = 1. So ```(i + 1) % list.length``` repeat 0, 1, 2 for a list of length 3.